# Forwarded email detection

Tags: email

Is there any way to detect (using RFC 2822 headers) that an email is a forwarded email?

Comment: Do you mean "forwarded" as in setting a forwarding address so that all mail is automatically redirected to a different mailbox, or "forwarded" as in clicking on the "Forward" button in your mailer and entering a recipient email address and some descriptive text?

Comment: If the former, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742533/is-the-delivered-to-header-the-right-place-to-find-the-address-of-the-recipient-f and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739354/email-server-design-avoiding-loops

Comment: I meant the forward in an email client, like clicking in "Forward"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two things that are normally referred to as "forwarding".

When you set up automatic account-level forwarding to another email address, your mail system will usually introduce an extra header to enable it to detect and break mail loops.  Unfortunately, the name of this header has never been standardized.  [Some use `Delivered-To`, some use `X-Loop`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-palme-mailext-headers-08), some use `X-Original-To`, some use an X-header proprietary to their mail software.  But there's no single header field that's present all cases.

When you manually forward a message by clicking the "Forward" button in your mailer and entering a recipient email address and some descriptive text, a new message with a new `Message-ID` header is generated.  The set of headers on this message will be indistinguishable from a normal reply -- `In-Reply-To` and `References` are set in exactly the same way.  The only difference is that the `Subject` header will *usually* start with "`Fwd:`" or end with "`(fwd)`".  ("Usually" because some clients format it as "`[Fwd: <original subject>]`" with square brackets around the new subject, some clients localize the prefix `Fwd:` into their own language, and some users manually edit the `Subject` before hitting "send".)

So there are good *hints* that a message is forwarded, but no hard and fast rules.

Comment: Do `In-Reply-To` and `References` appear in (1) an automatically forward message (2) an automatically reply message ?

Comment: Does `Subject` appear in a reply message? If it is not we can easily distinguish a reply message from a forward message

Comment: Reply message, will have a subject start with `"Re: "`. I'm building a custom email puller to create Jira Issue/Comment. This have busted me, can I safely distinguish Forward/Reply email base on Subject field?

Answer (score 5):

Reading the [spec](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), CTRL+F for "forward" gives the following header fields:

```
resent-date     =       "Resent-Date:" date-time CRLF  
resent-from     =       "Resent-From:" mailbox-list CRLF  
resent-sender   =       "Resent-Sender:" mailbox CRLF  
resent-to       =       "Resent-To:" address-list CRLF  
resent-cc       =       "Resent-Cc:" address-list CRLF  
resent-bcc      =       "Resent-Bcc:" (address-list / [CFWS]) CRLF
resent-msg-id   =       "Resent-Message-ID:" msg-id CRLF
```

I'm not sure whether the major mail software uses these though.

**EDIT**

Read the spec a little too quickly, there is also this note:

> Note: Reintroducing a message into the transport system and using
>      resent fields is a different operation from "forwarding".
>      "Forwarding" has two meanings: One sense of forwarding is that a mail
>      reading program can be told by a user to forward a copy of a message
>      to another person, making the forwarded message the body of the new
>      message.  A forwarded message in this sense does not appear to have
>      come from the original sender, but is an entirely new message from
>      the forwarder of the message.  On the other hand, forwarding is also
>      used to mean when a mail transport program gets a message and
>      forwards it on to a different destination for final delivery.  Resent
>      header fields are not intended for use with either type of
>      forwarding.

There are no other notices of "forwarding", so there are no header fields that you can use to detect the forward, except for the `subject = "Fwd: <msg>"` convention.