# Is the Delivered-To header the right place to find the address of the recipient for forwarded mail?

Tags: email, header

There is a mail processing script on example.com that processes emails sent to addresses like: account1234@example.com

The mail server has a catch-all for example.com and processes the email into the appropriate account.

For users who have setup up a forwarding rule from another email address I'm having trouble finding the right header to check for the account. For example if the user with account1234 has a gmail rule that forwards certain emails sent to user1234@gmail.com to account1234@example.com then the processing script will find user1234@gmail.com in the To: header and account1234@example.com in the Delivered-To: header.

Is that Delivered-To: header guaranteed to be there or is this specific to the mail server doing the forwarding?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's specific to the host doing the forwarding.  And it's not even there for your benefit -- it's there to allow the forwarding server [to detect and break mail loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739354/email-server-design-avoiding-loops).  (For instance, `a@example.com` forwards to `b@sample.com`, which forwards back to `a@example.com`.)  Various servers use different header fields for this purpose, and there is no formal standard.